# symfony twig translation not working after update

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I upgraded my project from 2.5.x to 2.8.1 and suddenly twig is not using the correct translations anymore.

In the twig template i have something like this:
`{% trans %}something.abc{% endtrans %}`

my config.yml looks like this:

```
...
framework:
    translator:      ~
...
templating:
    engines: ['twig']
default_locale:  en_US
```

in Controller action:

```
$request->setLocale('nl_BE');
```

The page is always showing the en_US translation and never something else.

Did something change?

Comment: It is because the `TranslatorListener` (https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/v2.8.2/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/EventListener/TranslatorListener.php) sets the locale before the action is called in your controller. Use `$this->get('translator')->setLocale('nl_BE');` instead.

Comment: @Fracsi Genius that works! You can put it as an answer and then we can close this issue? btw did something change or have I been doing this wrong in 2.5 as well?

Comment: 2.5 Did not have a `TranslatorListener`. Answer added.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because the [`TranslatorListener`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/v2.8.2/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/EventListener/TranslatorListener.php) (which was added in 2.6) sets the locale before the action is called in your controller. Use `$this->get('translator')->setLocale('nl_BE');` instead, if you want to change the locale in your controller.