# Symfony : sticky locale doesnt work

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to follow the "Making the Locale "Sticky" during a User's Session" Symfony tutorial but, I've got an error and I don't know why...

When I click on a flag to change language, the new language is set in session and, after the redirect, I've got the selected language in "$request->getLocale()" **BUT not in the translator**... Do you have an idea of the problem ? Thank very much !

Edit : I just want use locale by session

LocaleListener.php

```php
<?php
// src/AppBundle/EventListener/LocaleListener.php
namespace AppBundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;

class LocaleListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private $defaultLocale;

    public function __construct($defaultLocale = 'fr')
    {
        $this->defaultLocale = $defaultLocale;
    }

    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $request = $event->getRequest();
        if (!$request->hasPreviousSession()) {
            return;
        }

        if ($locale = $request->attributes->get('_locale')) {
            $request->getSession()->set('_locale', $locale);
        } else {
            // Si aucune locale n'a été fixée explicitement dans la requête, on utilise celle de la session
            $request->setLocale($request->getSession()->get('_locale', $this->defaultLocale));
        }
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            // must be registered after the default Locale listener
            KernelEvents::REQUEST => array(array('onKernelRequest', 17)),
        );
    }
}
```

change_language.html.twig (to change the language)

```
<a href="{{ path('app_change_language', {'language': key}) }}" >key</a>
```

LanguageController.php

```php
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use AppBundle\Form\Model\Language\Language;
use AppBundle\Form\Type\LanguageType;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

/**
 * Class LanguageController.
 */
class LanguageController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/changelanguage/{language}", name="app_change_language", options={"expose"=true})
     *
     * @param Request $request
     *
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     */
    public function setLanguageAction(Request $request, $language = null)
    {

        $defaultLanguage = $request->getLocale();

        // pour test
        $languages = [
            'fr' => 'French',
            'gb' => 'English',
            'es' => 'Spanish',

        ];

        if(isset($language))
        {


            $this->get('session')->set("_locale", $language);

            $url = $this->generateUrl('app_homepage');
            return $this->redirect($url);

        }

        return $this->render('AppBundle:Language:change_language.html.twig',  array(
                   'languages' => $languages,
                   'defaultLanguage' => $defaultLanguage)
                );
    }
}
```

app/config/services.xml

```yml
  app.eventListeners.locale_listener:
      class: AppBundle\EventListener\LocaleListener
      arguments: ["%kernel.default_locale%"]
      tags:
          - { name: kernel.event_subscriber }
```

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34981732/symfony-twig-translation-not-working-after-update

Comment: Thank Fracsi but it doesn't work. The translator uses the default locale even if I force it with the locale from "$request->getLocale()" in my defaultController.php.

Comment: I don't know what I'm doing bad :(

Comment: I found something interesting and really weird. In TranslatorListener (setLocale method, symfony sources), the locale is the good one. How is it possible ? TranslatorListener has the good locale and it's still the bad translation file used... ???

Comment: Finally, I found why... Translator gets the good locale but an external bundle (lexik translation) replaced it each time... now it works !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the answer :

> Finally, I found why... Translator gets the good locale but an external bundle (lexik translation) replaced it each time... now it works !

Comment: how did you solve this? I have the exact same problem and I use the same bundles but I don't really what to had to avoid lexik to change the local

Answer (score 0):

Following Fracsi's answer :

DefaultController :

```php
<?php 

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Cookie;

    /**
     * Class DefaultController.
     */
    class DefaultController extends AbstractController
    {

        /**
         * @Route("/", name="app_homepage")
         *
         * @param Request $request
         *
         * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
         */
        public function indexAction(Request $request)
        {
            $locale     = $request->getLocale();
            // locale = "gb" (after click on the flag and redirect)

            $translator = $this->get('translator');

            var_dump($translator->getLocale()); // fr

            $this->get('translator')->setLocale('gb');

            var_dump($this->get('translator')->getLocale()); // display "gb"
            var_dump($translator->trans('menu.home')); // display translation in french...

        }
```